# Cordova Android mediaDevices.getUserMedia instantly pausing

Tags: javascript, cordova, mediadevices

I have having problems is a camera within a cordova app.

The below code works with browsers, cordova iphone and both android and iphone browsers but no a compiled cordova app on android.

```
const constraints = {
            audio: false,
            video: {
                    width: {min: 800, ideal: 1024, max: 1280},
                    height: {min: 600},
                    facingMode: {exact: 'user'}
                   }
            }
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
                .then(Stream => {
                    localMediaStream = Stream;
                    if ('srcObject' in video) {
                        console.log("Stream");
                        video.srcObject = Stream;
                    } else {
                        console.log("Stream Src");
                        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(Stream);                     
                    }

                    video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                        video.play();
                    };
                    
                    //video.play();

                    window.addEventListener("onbeforeunload", function(event) {     
                        //const tracks = Stream.getTracks();
                        const tracks = localMediaStream.getTracks();
                        tracks.forEach(function(track) {
                            track.stop();
                            console.log("Stop Track");
                        })
                        video.srcObject = null;
                        //Stream = null;
                        localMediaStream = null;
                    })


                })
                .catch(err => {
                    alert("Camera Not Supported");
                    console.log(err);
                });
```

I have a permission check around the code and the camera will initially display the stream but instantly pauses leaving a still image on the screen.
If i touch the mobile screen in any location the camera video works perfect until I take my finger off the screen when it pauses again.

Any Ideas?

Comment: How and when do you call `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the problem by using:

```
video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                    video.play();
                    setInterval(drawVideoFrame, 100);
                };

function drawVideoFrame() {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);      
        }
```

It now works perfectly in all the browsers i've tried inc mobile cordova.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your CSP (Content Security Policy) meta tag in the head of your html file to stop this issue.

It should contain something like:

```
media-src 'self' mediastream: data: blob: *; 
img-src 'self' data: blob: android-webview-video-poster: *;
```

Offloading frames via setInterval to render to canvas is very expensive and best used for only taking snapshot pictures.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem by adding a block with an infinite animation:

```
<div class="fake">
 m
</div>
```

The CSS code for the block is:

```
.fake {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: transparent;
  font-size: 1px;
  animation: rotate 100s infinite;
  z-index: -100;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

The animation is defined with the following keyframes:

```
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```